# How to route internet traffic through DD-WRT OpenVPN connection

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, dd-wrt

I am looking to setup an OpenVPN server, on my home router, flashed with DD-WRT. There are many guides online on how to do this, such as this [one](https://www.howtogeek.com/64433/how-to-install-and-configure-openvpn-on-your-dd-wrt-router/).

Most of the guides online seem to stop at the point where you connect with an OpenVPN to the client, and then you are able to access devices on your home network. What step(s) do I need to take from there to route all internet traffic from VPN clients (e.g. my smart phone/laptops connected to public wifi's), such that all internet traffic from those client devices get routed through my home network?

My question is similar to this [one](https://superuser.com/questions/57053/routing-all-internet-traffic-through-home-network/57857) except in this case, I already have a VPN client and server in mind, and I'm guessing there is just some extra configuration necessary to route my client internet traffic (e.g. my smartphone while connected to a coffee shop wifi) through my home network.

The [question/answers here](https://superuser.com/questions/120069/routing-all-traffic-through-openvpn-tunnel) seem to imply I need to set routing settings on my client devices, but is that possible if I'm using an android smartphone (not rooted)?

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Not yet. I saw some reddit posts on openvpn client configuraiton but havent had a chance to try those yet. if you happen to figure it out I'm all ears.